# Block Yandex crawler

Tags: web-crawlers, yandex

Our site has been behaving very strangely for the last few days, lots of time outs etc.  Finally think I found the cause, the Yandex bot is crawling around 10,000 pages an hour!  I need to stop it ASAP, I think that's creating around 50-100gb of bandwidth usage per day.

**Blocked IP's** (via https://myip.ms/info/bots/Google_Bing_Yahoo_Facebook_etc_Bot_IP_Addresses.html):

> 100.43.90.0/24, 37.9.115.0/24, 37.140.165.0/24, 77.88.22.0/25, 77.88.29.0/24, 77.88.31.0/24, 77.88.59.0/24, 84.201.146.0/24, 84.201.148.0/24, 84.201.149.0/24, 87.250.243.0/24, 87.250.253.0/24, 93.158.147.0/24, 93.158.148.0/24, 93.158.151.0/24, 93.158.153.0/32, 95.108.128.0/24, 95.108.138.0/24, 95.108.150.0/23, 95.108.158.0/24, 95.108.156.0/24, 95.108.188.128/25, 95.108.234.0/24, 95.108.248.0/24, 100.43.80.0/24, 130.193.62.0/24, 141.8.153.0/24, 178.154.165.0/24, 178.154.166.128/25, 178.154.173.29, 178.154.200.158, 178.154.202.0/24, 178.154.205.0/24, 178.154.239.0/24, 178.154.243.0/24, 37.9.84.253, 199.21.99.99, 178.154.162.29, 178.154.203.251, 178.154.211.250, 95.108.246.252, 5.45.254.0/24, 5.255.253.0/24, 37.140.141.0/24, 37.140.188.0/24, 100.43.81.0/24, 100.43.85.0/24, 100.43.91.0/24, 199.21.99.0/24

**My robots.txt:**

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: ... etc
```

But it's still apparently crawling as reported by Cloudflare.

What else can I do to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

Right from Yandex website

```
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yandex...) string identifies Yandex robots. Robots
can send GET (for example, YandexBot/3.0) and HEAD (YandexWebmaster/2.0) requests to a
server. A reverse DNS lookup can be used to check the authenticity of Yandex robots. More
information can be found in the How to check that a robot belongs to Yandex section of
the Webmaster help.

If you have any questions about our robots, please contact our support service:
support@search.yandex.com. If you are experiencing technical issues with our robots
we recommend attaching your server log.
```

You can email their team and request they don't crawl your server or block the correct user-agent. If your server is overloaded and cannot keep up with the robot download requests, you should use the Crawl-delay directive. It will allow you to specify the minimum amount of time (in seconds) between the search robot downloading one page and starting the next.

Examples:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Crawl-delay: 2 # specifies a 2 second timeout
```

and

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Crawl-delay: 4.5 # specifies a 4.5 second timeout
```

Comment: Thanks, have emailed them.  Still looking for a way to pull the plug.

Comment: @TomGullen I have updated my answer for you. Try using the `Crawl-delay` command AFTER your deny line to limit how often the bot crawls your site.